# Simple differentiation from first principles problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know this is really basic, but how do I differentiate this equation from first principles to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$:

$$
y = \frac{1}{x}
$$

I tried this:

$$\begin{align}
f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} & = \lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[ \frac{f(x + \delta x) - f(x)}{\delta x} \right] \\
& = \lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[ \frac{(x+\delta x)^{-1} - x^{-1}}{\delta x} \right] \\
& = \lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[ \frac{1}{\delta x(x + \delta x )} - \frac{1}{x(\delta x)} \right] \\
& = \lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[ \frac{1}{x(\delta x)} + \frac{1}{(\delta x)^2} - \frac{1}{x(\delta x)} \right] \\
& = 1
\end{align}$$

which is obviously wrong, since $f'(x) = - \frac{1}{x^2}$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: how do you get from the third line to the fourth in your equation?

Comment: Take the third line and reduce to same denominator.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily  hold that $\frac 1{a+b}=\frac 1a+\frac 1b$.

Comment: Yes as @HartoSaarinen mentions, they are not equal. Thats where you went wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} & = \lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[ \frac{f(x + \delta x) - f(x)}{\delta x} \right] \\
& = \lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[ \frac{(x+\delta x)^{-1} - x^{-1}}{\delta x} \right] \\
& = \lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[\color{blue}{ \frac{1}{\delta x(x + \delta x )}} - \frac{1}{x(\delta x)} \right] \\
& = \lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[ \color{blue}{\frac{1}{x(\delta x)} + \frac{1}{(\delta x)^2}} - \frac{1}{x(\delta x)} \right] \\
& = 1
\end{align}$$

Highlighted in blue is the mistaken step you took. Namely, you fell prey to the fallacy which is rarely true: $$\frac 1{a+b} =  \frac 1a + \frac 1b\tag{fallacy}$$

The fallacy stems, I think, from the fact that we can split a sum when it's in the numerator, like thus, $$\frac {a+b}{c} = \frac ac + \frac bc$$ but we cannot do so when the sum is in the denominator.

What you *can* do is find the common denominator of the two terms (fractions) in the third line above, and then all should progress smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[ \frac{1}{\delta x(x + \delta x )} - \frac{1}{x(\delta x)} \right]=\lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[\frac{-\delta x-x}{x\delta x (\delta x+x)}+\frac{x}{x\delta x (\delta x+x)} \right ]=\lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[-\frac{\delta x}{x\delta x(x+\delta x)} \right]=\lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[\frac{-1}{x(x+\delta x)}\right ]=\lim_{\delta x\to 0} \left[\frac{-1}{x\delta x+x^2}\right ]=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

This is as detailed as it can go I think.

Remember that $$\frac{1}{a+b} \neq \frac1a +\frac1b, \forall a,b$$

Answer (score 2):

You did some strange calculation to arrive at the fourth line. I prefer to use $h$ instead of $\delta x$. Then
$$\frac{1}{h}\left( \frac{1}{x+h} - \frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{1}{h} \frac{x-x-h}{x(x+h)} = \frac{-1}{x(x+h)} $$
which does what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} f(x+h)-f(x) &= \dfrac{1}{x+h} - \dfrac{1}{x} \\ &=  \dfrac{x-h-x}{x(x+h)} \\ &= \dfrac{-h}{x(x+h)} \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f^{´}(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \displaystyle \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} =$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\displaystyle \frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\displaystyle \frac{\frac{x-x-h}{x(x+h)}}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\displaystyle \frac{\frac{-h}{x(x+h)}}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\displaystyle \frac{-h}{hx(x+h)}$$

$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\displaystyle \frac{-1}{x^{2}+xh}= \frac{-1}{x^{2}} $$